# ls colors disappear after running zsh

Tags: macos, colors, zsh, ls, iterm2

I installed the latest version of zsh on my osx using brew and then went ahead and installed oh-my-zsh. 
Everything is fine and dandy, but where did my ls colors go? If I run a bash -l inside of that zsh and do ls in that bash, my ls is colorful again.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

well, that didn't take long, I should have suspected from the beginning.
zsh runs the GNU ls, whereas bash runs the default mac osx ls. hence the difference in behaviour. I don't know why or how zsh chooses gnu ls and how put the gnu ls there to begin with, but ATM I don't care. 
aliased 'ls' to 'ls --color' in zsh and I have my colorful ls again. yay! albeit the colors are a bit different.

Comment: `zsh` choses the application it runs like any other shell: If it is neither a builtin, a function or an alias, `zsh` checks the directories in `PATH`. If `PATH` differs between `zsh` and `bash`, it is likely that either or both change it in their in configs.

Comment: yep. in this particular case I had enabled oh-my-zsh's gnu-utils which makes all the available gnu based commands take precedence over their equivalent BSD based default OSX commands.